# Is it posible set a external IP at 192.168.1.X/24 in a kubernetes service?

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster located in 192.168.1.130. When I deploy services, those services are reachable from the cluster, but not from the rest of the devices in the network.

I have thought that one solution could be set a external IP at 192.168.1.X/24. Is it posible?

Comment: which kinda of setup do you have? you can have an internal ingress

Comment: Just a server connected to the router. The laptop, PC, etc... in the same network

Comment: Please update your question with the information about your kubernetes solution. Is it `minikube`, `Docker for Desktop`, `kubeadm` cluster? What is your OS? Is this cluster in a `VM`?

Answer (score 1):

Deploy nginx ingress controller, then setup an ingress object to port 80, if you are running k8s in your notebook or pc without a vm, then the service should be able to be reached from any device in the same network with `http://your-ip:80`

Example ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              service:
                name: your_service
                port:
                  number: 8080 #YourServicePort
```

Then all your requests will be forwarded to your_service:yourport